Are ethers, rarp, plipconfig and slattach commands deprecated and what are their replacements?
There are 10 networking tools in net-tools Debian package (and also other distros, probably the package is named differently):

arp (ip n)
ifconfig (ip)
mmi-tool (ethtool)
nameif (ip link)
netstat (ss)
route (ip r)
ethers
rarp
plipconfig
slattach

From the list above I know for certain that the first 6 of them are deprecated and there are known replacements as set out in parentheses.
But it's unclear about the other 4, are they deprecated as well and what are their replacements? these are:

ethers
rarp
plipconfig
slattach


The four you mention are not deprecated, they’re obsolete: they’re no longer useful and there’s no need for a replacement for them (except for some niche use cases).
ethers isn’t a program, it’s a file, /etc/ethers, containing MAC-to-IP-address mappings. It’s intended for use with arp -f but is rarely needed for that; as far as I’m aware ip n doesn’t support it. It is useful with dnsmasq, which can set static leases up using the information in /etc/ethers.
rarp was used to manipulate the kernel’s RARP table; the kernel dropped built-in support for RARP in 2.3, so this program is obsolete. If you need RARP (if you don’t know, you don’t), you should run a separate RARP daemon (rarpd on Debian).
plipconfig is used to configure PLIP (parallel line internet protocol) settings; it’s only useful if you have parallel ports and nothing better to use them for.
slattach is used to connect over serial lines. In practice if you’re doing that you’d use PPP.

They’re not deprecated, they’re obsolete how would you briefly define "deprecated" and "obsolete", aren't these terms meaning the same thing? And do you mean all 10 of them are obsolete or just the 4 I mentioned?

Found definitions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208091/the-difference-between-deprecated-depreciated-and-obsolete

Right, my definitions align with those — obsolete means the tools are already useless because the task they were used for is no longer relevant; deprecated means the tools are still available, the task they perform is still useful, but there’s a different (better?) way of doing things now.

/etc/ethers is useful when running a DHCP server - that's where I put the known interfaces that get fixed-address leases.

@TobySpeight thanks, which DHCP server implementation supports /etc/ethers?

That's with dnsmasq as DHCP server.  I think that read-ethers is a non-default option (but it's sat quietly running for many years since I last had to touch the config...)
